# Phalcon routing behaviour - redundant routes?

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm working with the following routing example:

https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/blob/master/simple-subcontrollers/app/config/routes.php

Can anyone explain to me why on line 12 there is this:

```
$router->add('/:controller', array(...
```

Haven't we already defined the route on line 5 as:

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params', array(
```

"**/:controller**" is a subset of '**/:controller/:action/:params**'.

If you remove "**/:controller**" route, URLs ending with controller name will not be matched.

Why isn't router falling back to default action name that I can indicate as:

```
$router->setDefaultAction('index');
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the answer clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action/:params', array(
```

Will only execute if it gets all parts to make the route valid for example

```
myapp/users/logout/dave
```

The above will match what that route is looking for and cause the route to execute.

```
myapp/users
```

The above however wouldn't match due to missing actions and params also a url with a / and without aren't the same url.

Since you can add many routes as you need using add(), the order in which routes are added indicate their relevance, lastest routes added have more relevance than first added. Internally, all defined routes are traversed in reverse order until Phalcon\Mvc\Router finds the one that matches the given URI and processes it, while ignoring the rest.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I decided to revive this in Phalcon forum: http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1823/router-url-generator